# Swift json parse fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, json, swift

Hello When i parse json data gives me fatal error my codes here

```
let queue = NSOperationQueue();
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(storeRequest, queue: queue, completionHandler: { (response : NSURLResponse?, data : NSData?, error : NSError?) -> Void in

    if(error != nil){
        //Handle Error
    }
    else{


        var jsonResponse: NSMutableDictionary?
        do{
            jsonResponse = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!,
                                                                      options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? NSMutableDictionary;


            print(jsonResponse)

            let info : NSArray =  jsonResponse!.valueForKey("latest_receipt_info") as! NSArray
            let transaction_id: String? = info[0].valueForKey("transaction_id") as? String
            let web_order_line_item_id: String? = info[0].valueForKey("web_order_line_item_id") as? String

    // ...
```

Error output

```
 fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Mark this line when fatal error

```
let info : NSArray =  jsonResponse!.valueForKey("latest_receipt_info") as! NSArray
```

I try but i dont resolve it

Also my json value

```
{
    environment = Sandbox;
    receipt =     {
        "adam_id" = 0;
        "app_item_id" = 0;
        "application_version" = "3.8";
        "bundle_id" = "com.bla.bla";
        "download_id" = 0;
        "in_app" =         (
                        {
                "is_trial_period" = false;
                "original_purchase_date" = "2016-02-18 15:56:23 Etc/GMT";
                "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1455810983000;
                "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2016-02-18 07:56:23 America/Los_Angeles";
                "original_transaction_id" = 1000000194749934;
                "product_id" = "com.bla.ShowMaps";
                "purchase_date" = "2016-02-18 15:56:23 Etc/GMT";
                "purchase_date_ms" = 1455810983000;
                "purchase_date_pst" = "2016-02-18 07:56:23 America/Los_Angeles";
                quantity = 1;
                "transaction_id" = 1000000194749934;
            },
                        {
                "is_trial_period" = false;
                "original_purchase_date" = "2016-02-18 15:58:37 Etc/GMT";
                "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1455811117000;
                "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2016-02-18 07:58:37 America/Los_Angeles";
                "original_transaction_id" = 1000000194750377;
                "product_id" = "com.bla.ApiSupport";
                "purchase_date" = "2016-02-18 15:58:37 Etc/GMT";
                "purchase_date_ms" = 1455811117000;
                "purchase_date_pst" = "2016-02-18 07:58:37 America/Los_Angeles";
                quantity = 1;
                "transaction_id" = 1000000194750377;
            },
                        {
                "is_trial_period" = false;
                "original_purchase_date" = "2016-02-18 17:13:03 Etc/GMT";
                "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1455815583000;
                "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2016-02-18 09:13:03 America/Los_Angeles";
                "original_transaction_id" = 1000000194763153;
                "product_id" = "com.bla.Limit";
                "purchase_date" = "2016-02-18 17:13:03 Etc/GMT";
                "purchase_date_ms" = 1455815583000;
                "purchase_date_pst" = "2016-02-18 09:13:03 America/Los_Angeles";
                quantity = 1;
                "transaction_id" = 1000000194763153;
            },
                        {
                "is_trial_period" = false;
                "original_purchase_date" = "2016-02-18 15:57:43 Etc/GMT";
                "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1455811063000;
                "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2016-02-18 07:57:43 America/Los_Angeles";
                "original_transaction_id" = 1000000194750331;
                "product_id" = "com.bla.BarcodeSupport";
                "purchase_date" = "2016-02-18 15:57:43 Etc/GMT";
                "purchase_date_ms" = 1455811063000;
                "purchase_date_pst" = "2016-02-18 07:57:43 America/Los_Angeles";
                quantity = 1;
                "transaction_id" = 1000000194750331;
            }
        );
        "original_application_version" = "1.0";
        "original_purchase_date" = "2013-08-01 07:00:00 Etc/GMT";
        "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1375340400000;
        "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2013-08-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles";
        "receipt_creation_date" = "2016-02-18 17:13:03 Etc/GMT";
        "receipt_creation_date_ms" = 1455815583000;
        "receipt_creation_date_pst" = "2016-02-18 09:13:03 America/Los_Angeles";
        "receipt_type" = ProductionSandbox;
        "request_date" = "2016-02-18 17:13:05 Etc/GMT";
        "request_date_ms" = 1455815585353;
        "request_date_pst" = "2016-02-18 09:13:05 America/Los_Angeles";
        "version_external_identifier" = 0;
    };
    status = 0;
}
```

How can i get inside json response example let product_id = mysender value ? so ;

like this ?

```
info = jsonResponse["receipt"]!["in_app"]
```

Thanks

Comment: I had the similar experience recently trying to fetch json array from a laravel json server. After a while noticed  there're some url values containing some slash letters, and encoded them on the back end to prevent from collapsing the json array structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from your `JSON` structure, which isn't specified, assuming it doesn't always return correctly, you need to account for it by not implicitly unwrapping the `JSON` object. You should also use pure Swift arrays instead of `NSArray`s, which are bridged to Objective-C when needed.

It is also good style to use subscripting when possible.

```
if let jsonResponse = jsonResponse,
  info = jsonResponse["latest_receipt_info"] {
  // Makes sense to check if count > 0 if you're not sure, but...
  let transaction_id = info[0]["transaction_id"] as? String
  let web_order_line_item_id = info[0]["web_order_line_item_id"] as? String
  // Do whatever else you need here
}
```

If I am understanding the second question correctly, you can get at that value by parsing the array and iterating through the objects to get at the `product_id`s, like so:

```
if let receipt = jsonResponse["receipt"],
  info = receipt["in_app"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
  for object in info {
    print(object["product_id"])
  }
}
```

...or something along those lines, since info is an array of objects. You might have to massage this to fit your purposes.

Comment: man how can i take that json values ? i added my codes under

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Which values?

Comment: i added my json output i want there  example ;  my product_id = "com.bla" is equal json output values i need

Comment: for object in info line gives  error : Value of type 'AnyObject?' has no member 'Generator'

Comment: Try casting info as the type of array you expect. See updated answer for recommendation.

Comment: also i want which product_id = myproduct_id string ? i want to get have values ? so in_app have 3 json output member of product_id

Comment: It may be good to review a tutorial on JSON with Swift, like [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/120442/swift-json-tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your jsonResponse (or the "latest_receipt_info" key) is nil. In this case you can't use '!' because this means you are sure that either one won't be nil. Instead, first check with they exist before do any operation.